# Azure B2C claims from sign up not coming through

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using ASP.NET Core 1.0 against Azure B2C with a policy that includes sign up information like postal code and address. Although the policy has been configured to include this data as claims, I am not seeing them in on the user claims in .NET when logging in with a Google or Microsoft account. Is there additional configuration needed to include user claims? I have also set GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint on the OpenIdConnectOptions but that did not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with Azure AD B2C instances that were created during preview. Just create a new instance and it works.